# Hosting public app for shopify

Tags: web-hosting, shopify

What is the best place to land public app for shopify? Is there anything else beside heroku?  Is it worth to build and support own infrastructure or it is better to leverage that on cloud solution?

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of cloud solutions out there. AWS, Nitrous, Rackspace...

Comment: After pushing this question I found this post. It is very helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162144/what-are-the-good-ruby-on-rails-hosting-service-out-there. Thank you Alex!

Answer (score 0):

Almost a year passed when I asked this question. So when I asked this question my thoughts were to have some sort of cloud service(may be provide by Shopify) that would natively integrate with Shopify platform. So I just publish my app and would scale whenever app start getting popularity. I was newbie to this :) and did not know many things. And I am still learning ... :)

Nowadays our env gets change quite rapidly. So just wanted to share my experience however it is still too see yet since customer base is still growing and we did not hit our first bottleneck in our infrastructure. We were fortunate being accepted to Microsoft BizSpark program which allowed us to focus on building product and leverage Microsoft Azure infrastructure as much as possible. When we initially started we choose Rails as our backend and front-end solution but we soon realized it is becoming hard to manage when application start growing that is when we started to think how to divorce backend and front-end. This split brought a lot of changes in infra.  Even now it is still evolving and we gradually started moving toward containerization as for our backend solution which is bringing a lot changes too.  So what I am trying to say it is always best to start with something small and free, and if things get change you can always reevaluate. As far as my personal favorite cloud provider I would choose - Gcloud.